# Character Widths different on Vista and Windows 7

Tags: windows, text, width, character

Why do I get different values for character widths on Vista and
Windows 7 64 bit? I'm using Delphi's Canvas.TextWidth to tell me the
widths of the characters. TextWidth calls the Windows function
GetTextExtentPoint32. The tahoma.ttf files on both computers are
identical. Both computers have Windows set to use 96 dpi. Turning off
Clear Type has no effect. Vista is on a desktop. Windows 7 64 bit is
on a laptop. I tried attaching my desktop monitor to the laptop; this
did not change the laptop results.

Both computers report the following:

```
Tahoma
Size:               10
Height:             13
PixelsPerInch:      96
tmHeight:           16
tmAscent:           13
tmDescent:          3
tmInternalLeading:  3
tmExternalLeading:  0
tmAveCharWidth:     6
tmWeight:           400
tmOverhang:         0
tmDigitizedAspectX: 96
tmDigitizedAspectY: 96
tmCharSet:          ANSI_CharSet
```

tmMaxCharWidth is 27 on Windows 7 64 bit and 35 on Vista.

In the following, the first column is the character, the next is the
character width on Vista, and the third the character width on Windows
7 64 bit.

```
0  7   7
1  7   7
2  7   7
3  7   7
4  7   7
5  7   7
6  7   7
7  7   7
8  7   7
9  7   7

A  9   8
B  9   7
C  9   8
D  9   8
E  9   7
F  8   7
G  10  8
H  9   8
I  3   4
J  6   5
K  9   7
L  7   6
M  11  10
N  9   8
O  10  9
P  9   7
Q  10  9
R  9   8
S  9   8
T  7   8
U  9   8
V  9   8
W  13  12
X  7   8
Y  9   7
Z  7   7

a  7   7
b  7   7
c  7   6
d  7   7
e  7   7
f  3   4
g  7   7
h  7   7
i  3   3
j  3   4
k  7   6
l  3   3
m  11  11
n  7   7
o  7   7
p  7   7
q  7   7
r  4   5
s  7   6
t  4   4
u  7   7
v  5   6
w  9   10
x  7   6
y  7   6
z  7   6
```

Comment: Just like programs, fonts also have versions.  Vista has Tahoma version 5.01, Win7 has version 5.06, Win8 has version 5.25.  You cannot expect identical values for such a crude property as tmMaxCharWidth.  Pixel grid fitting and TrueType hinting are by themselves enough to explain differences.  DirectWrite is a text rendering api that preserves typographic metrics, unlike GDI which favors fitting the pixel grid.

Comment: Even though tahoma.ttf was version 5.10 on both computers, it seems there was something odd on the desktop. "Tahoma" was not listed when I viewed the fonts folder in Explorer. So, I copied the font file to another folder and had Explorer install it. Now, the character widths match the widths on the laptop.

Comment: Hot damn, what on Earth were you doing?  Please delete your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. I have no idea how the font could be in the Fonts folder, but not installed, and didn't even realize this was possible.